# Place an image behind a table

Tags: tables, graphics

I have a table in my document that holds preliminary data and I'd like to mark this by putting an image behind the table. How can I achieve this?

[image]

This is a mockup of what I'd like to achieve but if possible with the text in the background instead of in front.

Comment: a handrawn sketch of the desired output would be helpful

Comment: added a small mockup

Comment: please see if the answer meets requirement -- you can change the background color with `\color{black!40}` --font size with `\fontsize{8}{6}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, lmodern}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,tikzmark}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \node [yshift=.6ex,rotate=45] at ( $(pic cs:A) !.5! (pic cs:B)$ ){ \fontsize{8} 
          {6}\selectfont\textbf{\color{black!40}RESTRICTED} };
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \begin{tabular}{llll}
        1 & 2 & 3 & \tikzmark{B}4 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
        \tikzmark{A}1 & 2 & 3 & 4
    \end{tabular}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do I need the `lmodern` package for?

Comment: please remove the package since not required